# Create textbox dynamically in td next to specified td in html table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

Hello all,
I need to create textbox dynamically(depending on condition), when user clicks on employee it should get added next to employee, if user clicks on another element, it should get added next to another element

I have tried following, but I am not able to get exact td and function by which i can append textbox to it.

```
$("#emlpyeetd").after('<s:textfield id="employeeVal" name="employeeView.policyOrQuoteNumber" maxlength="15" style="width: 200px;" class="hideForAnotherField" theme="simple"></s:textfield>');


<td width="25%">
  employee
</td>
<td id="policytd" class= "anotherfield" width="25%"></td>
```

Comment: Can you give jsfiddle with your tried code?

Comment: Post your `html` and yea whatever you've tried to achieve so far..

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to add my code. Please find my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, it will remove 1st textbox when you click on 2nd option.

**Jquery code**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".radio_action").click(function(){

        if($(this).val() == "E" ){ 

            $("#other_text").html(""); 
            $("#emp_text").html("<input type='text' >"); 
        }
        else if($(this).val() == "A" ) { 
            $("#emp_text").html("");        
            $("#other_text").html("<input type='text' >"); 
        }
    })      
});
</script>
```

**HTML code**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio_type" value="E" class="radio_action" /> Employee</td>
    <td id="emp_text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio_type" value="A" class="radio_action" /> Another Element</td>
    <td id="other_text"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Html

<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div><input type="radio"/ name="somename" value="1">Val1</div>
    <div class="editor-wrapper"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div><input type="radio"/ name="somename" value="1">Val2</div>
    <div  class="editor-wrapper"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[name="somename"]').click(function() {
    $(this.closest('.container')).find('.editor-wrapper').html($('<input>'))
   });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ntedcg2/)